# Bootstrap Datepicker: Misaligned

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to implement a [bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) for a website. The issue is that the calendar modal becomes misaligned since some of the css  (which I don't have access to) adds a margin to the body and the modal is positioned absolutely.

```js
$('.input-test').datepicker({});
```

```css
body {
 margin-top: 110px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input class="input-test"></input>
```

[Here is jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lx6kzo1/6/) demonstrating the problem.

What's the easiest work around? Adding a fixed top margin through javascript  would work but is incredibly hacky. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the container element according to the documentation? https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#container

Comment: Yeah, I run into the same issue with setting it to a div next to the input.

Comment: Well ok apparently all I needed to do was set the container to the html tag, doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.input-test').datepicker({ container: "html" });`

That should fix the issue, here is a link to a fork of your jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/q0s4Lubb/